# Usage of 2D array in C++ globally

Tags: c++, dynamic, pthreads, multidimensional-array

My problem is that i want update a matrix with multiplication of two matrix , using threads . Following is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int thread_count; // For Command Line Argument
int l;
int m;
int n;
int start_Task;
int stop_Task;

void *Hello(void* rank); // Prototype of a thread function

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{      
int thread_id;

thread_count = atoi(argv[1]);
int l = atoi(argv[2]);  
int m = atoi(argv[3]);  
int n = atoi(argv[4]);  

int A[l][m]; //creates A l*m matrix or a 2d array. 

for(int i=0; i<l; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        A[i][j] = i+j; // Allocating values to A matrix
    }
}

int B[m][n]; //creates B m*n matrix or a 2d array.
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        B[i][j] = i+j+1; // Allocating values to B matrix
    }
}

int C[l][n]; //creates C m*n matrix or a 2d array.

int remainder = l % thread_count;
int allocatedProcess = l/thread_count;
start_Task =0; 
//cout<<remainder<<" "<<allocatedProcess<<endl;
pthread_t myThreads[thread_count]; 

//creates a certain number of threads
for(thread_id = 0; thread_id < thread_count; thread_id++)
   {    
    stop_Task = start_Task + allocatedProcess;
    pthread_create(&myThreads[thread_id], NULL,Hello, (void*)thread_id);
start_Task = stop_Task; 
}

cout<<"Hello from the main thread \n"<<endl;

for(int i=0; i<l; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        cout<<"Values in Final Matrix is"<<C[i][j]<<endl;
    }
}
 //wait until all threads finish
 for(thread_id = 0; thread_id<thread_count; thread_id++)        
pthread_join(myThreads[thread_id],NULL);

 return 0;
 }//main

 void *Hello(void* rank)
 {
for(int i=start_Task; i<stop_Task; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int k=0; k<m; k++) //This loops on the columns
        {
             sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j]; // Allocating values to C matrix
              //product[row][col] += aMatrix[row][inner] * bMatrix[inner][col];
            }
     C[i][j] = sum;
    cout << C[i][j] << "  ";
          }
       cout << "\n";
}

  int my_rank = (long)rank;

  cout<<"Thread_"<<my_rank<<" of "<<thread_count<<endl;

  return NULL;
  }
```

The problem i am facing is that i am unable to make my Matrix initialise globally as dimensions are itself global. Please update me correct way to impliment it.

Comment: If there is any work around please update ////

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that arrays in C and C++ must be setup with constants, not variables.

l and m in your example are not constants.  You can use std::vector.  If you are using a C++11 compiler then you have several other options.  Here is one thread that might help, but seriously; google "2d dynamic arrays c++" and see what else turns up.  It'll be a good exercise for you and will save me from copying and pasting from all of those wonderful articles!

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12409/

Comment: Arrays in C can be set up with variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring a pointer.

```
int *my_array;
```

In any method you can use the folowing lines:

```
std::cin >> n;
my_array = new int[n];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: My only critique of your answer is that the link is to a C question, and not a C++ question.